# Non-repeating Regex Pattern - negative lookahead

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am attempting to parse a string with regex in Java that is used for dimensions and return only the required parts of it.

The ideal String would be: number x number.

Anything not in this format can be ignored and return null.

Some of the Strings that are inputted include the following though.

- 123x 132 sqft
- 200 sq.ft. x 310 sq.ft.
- 404X931X1007X1140
- .772 Acres
- 680 and 3209.05
- 0.772 AC
- approx 255 by 640
- 111'X301'
- approx. 2 acre

My current regex solution is this

```
"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?)[^\\dxX]*(?:[xX]| and |by|\\*)[^\\dxX]*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?)"
```

and i return match.group(1) + "x" + match.group(2)

The problem I am left with is these repeating ones like "404X931X1007X1140"
This should also be returned as a null since its an irregular shape but instead returns 404x931

My question is how would I make sure not to include these?
My thought was to append a negative lookahead but it fails to meet my expectations and returns 404x93 for some reason.

```
first expression + "\\D*(?!([xX]| and |by|\\*)\\d+)"
```

Comment: Honestly, looking at the input, you'd probably be better off with using a parser. Even a simple one that's just a series of regexes you try until one matches

Comment: Try using word boundaries `\b` on the left and right of the pattern https://regex101.com/r/HtkEDO/1

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone else is looking for this. I ended up figuring out a solution that worked. I would have just used \b at the end but it didn't work for * characters.
And the {0,30} in the lookbehind is because java wont let me do infinite quantifiers in a lookbehind. Kind of a mess to look at though.

```
(?<!\\d(?:[xX]| and |by|\\*).{0,30})\\b(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*(?:\\.\\d+)?)[^\\dxX]*(?:[xX]| and |by|\\*)[^\\dxX]*(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*(?:\\.\\d+)?)(?!.*(?:[xX]| and |by|\\*)\\D*\\d+)
```